# foreach loop keeps repeating from beginning inside for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

After I executed a query, I used foreach ($result as $row) to get data from each found row from database and I used this inside for loop, I had no problem.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$num_rows=$result->rowCount();
for($i=1;$i<=$num_rows;$i++){
    foreach ($result as $row) { 
        echo "$i - $row[posttile]";break 1;
    }
}
```

Result looks like this:

```
1 - Post a
2 - Post b
...
```

However, I applied the principle to print each value in a array, the foreach loop keep repeating from the start:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
    foreach($array as $post){
        echo "$i - $post";break 1;
    }
}
```

But the result that it kept printing post a every time?

```
1 - Post a
2 - Post a
3 - Post a
...
```

How to fix this code to to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Post the array structure of `$result`

Comment: Here it is: $sql="SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$num_rows=$result->rowCount();

Comment: You are fetching data from ``$result`` which has all the records for every iterations. So you are getting same data. You can remove ``for`` loop and use only ``foreach``

Comment: put `$post=""` after echo

Comment: I wonder what will happen if you remove the `break 1;`. And how do you assign the result to `$array`, with a loop or fetchAll ?